# Java - Object/Signature

Tags: java, object

I came by a term out of thought with objects. When we extend a class, the extend class will have the same signature as the parent class, therefore the term IS-A comes from... example

```
class Foo{

}

class Foo2 extends Foo{

}

class Foo3 extends Foo{

}
```

But does that not mean that Foo2 IS-A Foo3, because they have extended the same class?

Comment: Would it make sense if they all had the same signature?

Comment: What is a signature?

Comment: signature for what?? method!!!!!

Comment: Classes don't have signatures. Your thinking is wrong.

Comment: `foo is a object and foo, foo2 is a foo2, foo and object` is it that what you are asking for/

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaining of question

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a definition for such thing as "class signature". However, if I get your concerns correctly, I would say - there is no problem with different classes extending the same base class, because the derived classes will have a different name hence they can be distinguished. In general a class is identified by its fully-qualified name which includes the package name and the class name.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaining of question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by signature?

But the following can be expressed:

```
Object object = new Object();
System.out.println(object instanceof Object);     // true
System.out.println(object instanceof Foo);        // false
System.out.println(object instanceof Foo2);       // false

Foo foo = new Foo();
System.out.println(foo instanceof Object);        // true
System.out.println(foo instanceof Foo);           // true
System.out.println(foo instanceof Foo2);          // false

Foo2 foo2 = new Foo2();
System.out.println(foo2 instanceof Object);       // true
System.out.println(foo2 instanceof Foo);          // true
System.out.println(foo2 instanceof Foo2);         // true


System.out.println(object.getClass().getName());  //  java.lang.Object
System.out.println(foo.getClass().getName());     //  Foo
System.out.println(foo2.getClass().getName());    //  Foo2
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaining of question

Answer (score 1):

Classes don't have signature.

If you mean the same interface you need to use **implements** and define an **interface**. An interface defines only the signature of his methods so all the classes deriving from it must implements his methods using exactly the signature you defined in it.

You can also do something similar using an **abstract class**.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaining of question

Comment: No problem, programming is tiring and tired people make errors. I hope my explenation can help you

Comment: Still, even with an normal class, you can override methods when you extend them. I just thought seeing as methods having a signature, an object would have too.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the literal meaning of the `IS-A` statement. Better you think on it like `IS-ALSO-A` so foo2 is-also-a foo and foo3 is-also-a foo, but foo2 is not a foo3 nor viceversa.

Indeed Foo2 `is-a` Foo plus something more.

Answer (score 1):

No Foo2 is not a Foo1 (also vice versa). 
Consider this: 
Parrot is-a bird, Ostrich is-a bird - that doesn't mean parrot is-a ostrich (or vice versa)

A small code for this will explain

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo1();
        Foo foo2 = new Foo2();
        Foo1 foo = new Foo2(); // won't work
    }
}

class Foo {
}

class Foo1 extends Foo {
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
}
```